# Apache - finding configuration file path

Tags: windows, apache, server

I have to migrate another apache instance from 2.2 to 2.4 but I have one problem.

In Apache monitor I see multiple services running but I don't really know where apache .conf files are stored. In previous migrations from 2.2 to 2.4 I had them somewhere within conf folder. Apache is hosted on windows.

How do I find these conf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `httpd.exe -S` it will list the config files used by all VHOSTs